# How do I use MapElements and KV in together in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-beam

I wanted to do something like:

```
PCollection<String> a = whatever;
PCollection<KV<String, User>> b = a.apply(
        MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(KV<String, User>.class))
        .via(s -> KV.of(s, new User(s))));
```

Where User is a custom datatype with Arvo coder and a constructor that takes a string into account.

However, I get the following error:

> Cannot select from parameterized type

I tried to change it to `TypeDescriptor.of(KV.class)` instead, but then I get:

> Incompatible types; Required PCollection> but 'apply' was inferred to OutputT: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exists so that PCollection conforms to PCollection>

So how am I suppose to use `KV` with `MapElements`?

I know that what I want to do is doable using `ParDo` where I could explicitly specify how to do Type Erasure by declearing `new DoFn<String, KV<String, User>>` but `ParDo` does not support lambda function. As we are using Java 8, this seems less elegant....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [type erasure in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) during compilation, `KV<String, User>.class` is transformed into `KV.class` and at runtime `KV.class` isn't enough information to infer a coder since the type variables have been erased.

To get around this limitation, you need to use a mechanism which preserves type information after compilation. For example you could use:

```
TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptor.of(User.class))
```

which is the same as providing your own anonymous class:

```
new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, User>> {}
```

Providing anonymous classes with type variables bound is one of the ways to get around type erasure in Java currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SimpleFunction - it preserves type info