# Why Apache beam can't infer the default coder when using KV<String, String>?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm implementing the [CombinePerKeyExample](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/cookbook/CombinePerKeyExamples.java) using a subclass of `CombineFn`  instead of using an implementation of `SerializableFunction`.

```java
package me.examples;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.DefaultCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine.CombineFn;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConcatWordsCombineFn extends CombineFn<String, ConcatWordsCombineFn.Accumulator, String> {
    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public static class Accumulator{
        HashSet<String> plays;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator createAccumulator(){
        Accumulator accumulator = new Accumulator();
        accumulator.plays = new HashSet<>();
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator addInput(Accumulator accumulator, String input){
        accumulator.plays.add(input);
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accumulator mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accumulator> accumulators){
        Accumulator mergeAccumulator = new Accumulator();
        mergeAccumulator.plays = new HashSet<>();

        for(Accumulator accumulator: accumulators){
            mergeAccumulator.plays.addAll(accumulator.plays);
        }

        return mergeAccumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public String extractOutput(Accumulator accumulator){
        return String.join(",", accumulator.plays);
    }
}
```

The pipeline is composed of a `ReadFromBigQuery`, `ExtractAllPlaysOfWords` (code below) and `WriteToBigQuery`

```java
package me.examples;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class PlaysForWord extends PTransform<PCollection<TableRow>, PCollection<TableRow>> {


    @Override
    public PCollection<TableRow> expand(PCollection<TableRow> input) {

            PCollection<KV<String, String>> largeWords = input.apply("ExtractLargeWords", ParDo.of(new ExtractLargeWordsFn()));

            //PCollection<KV<String, String>> wordNPlays = largeWords.apply("CombinePlays", Combine.perKey(new ConcatWordsCombineFunction()));
            //using CombineFn instead
            PCollection<KV<String, String>> wordNPlays = largeWords.apply("CombinePlays",Combine.perKey(new ConcatWordsCombineFn()));
            wordNPlays.setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()));
            PCollection<TableRow> rows = wordNPlays.apply("FormatToRow", ParDo.of(new FormatShakespeareOutputFn()));
            return rows;
    }
}
```

If I'm not adding this line in the code above

```java
 wordNPlays.setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()));
```

I'm having an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for ExtractAllPlaysOfWords/CombinePlays/Combine.GroupedValues/ParDo(Anonymous)/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).output [PCollection]. Correct one of the following root causes:
          No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
          Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<K, OutputT>: Unable to provide a Coder for K.
          Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
          See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
          Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v20_0.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:278)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:115)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:191)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:536)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:488)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:370)
                at me.examples.PlaysForWord.expand(PlaysForWord.java:21)
                at me.examples.PlaysForWord.expand(PlaysForWord.java:10)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:488)
                at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:370)
                at me.examples.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

From the stacktrace, I think the pipeline is not able to get a coder for the `String` type of the KV obejct. Why is that ? Isn't supposed to be a "known" type for Apache Beam. Why is it working without specifying the coder when using the subclass of `SerializableFunction` in the `Combine.perKey`?

In addition to that, when I tried to get the default coder for String from the coder registry I get `StringUTF8Coder`

```java
Coder coder = null;
       try {
           coder = pipeline.getCoderRegistry().getCoder(String.class);
           logger.info("coder is " + coder);
       } catch (Exception e){
           logger.info("exception "+ e.getMessage() +"\n coder is " + coder );
       }
/*result
INFO: coder is StringUtf8Coder
*/
```

I used Apache Beam 2.12.0 and run it on Google Dataflow

Comment: A large cause of coder inference issues is due to type erasure in Java (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53235553/4368200). For your example, I would suspect that it should have worked since your ConcatWordsCombineFn doesn't have any type variables declared. Can you add the message and stacktrace for the exception that is failing here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7c8530d550e5d687d5601b9fb09d6dbd6acb0302/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L2186 to your question?

Comment: @LukaszCwik How can I do that? The `apply` method is not throwing such an exception. I'm not seeing it in the Stacktrace.

Comment: Run the application in debug mode and add a breakpoint to https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7c8530d550e5d687d5601b9fb09d6dbd6acb0302/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L2186 Here are some guides https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html (Intellij) https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html (Eclipse)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the BUG. The above code is working without `wordNPlays.setCoder ...` line --'

Comment: Odd. If you can repro, feel free to update your question with additional details.