# How do I set the coder for a PCollection<List<String>> in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, json, apache-beam, jackson-databind

I'm teaching myself Apache Beam, specifically for using in parsing JSON. I was able to create a simple example that parsed JSON to a POJO and POJO to CSV. It required that I use `.setCoder()`
for my simple POJO class.

```
        pipeline
            .apply("Read source JSON file.", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput()))
            .apply("Parse to POJO matching schema", ParseJsons.of(Person.class))
            .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Person.class))
            .apply("Create comma delimited string", new PersonToCsvRow())
            .apply("Write out to file", TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput())
                .withoutSharding());
```

#### The problem

Now I am trying to skip the POJO step of parsing using some custom transforms. My pipeline looks like this:

```
        pipeline
            .apply("Read Json", TextIO.read().from("src/main/resources/family_tree.json"))
            .apply("Traverse Json tree", new JSONTreeToPaths())
            .apply("Format tree paths", new PathsToCSV())
            .apply("Write to CSV", TextIO.write().to("src/main/resources/paths.csv")
                .withoutSharding());
```

This pipeline is supposed to take a heavily nested JSON structure and print each individual path through the tree. I'm getting the same error I did in the POJO example above:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for Traverse Json tree/MapElements/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).output [PCollection@331122245]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
```

#### What I tried

So I tried to add a coder in a few different ways:

```
.setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(List<String>.class))
```

Results in "Cannot select from parameterized type". I found another instance of this error generated by a different use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235553/how-do-i-use-mapelements-and-kv-in-together-in-apache-beam), but the accepted answer seemed only be applicable to that use case.

So then I started perusing the Beam docs and found `ListCoder.of()` which has (literally) no description. But it looked promising, so I tried it:

```
.setCoder(ListCoder.of(SerializableCoder.of(String.class)))
```

But this takes me back to the initial error of not having manually set a coder.

#### The question

How do I satisfy this requirement to set a coder for a `List<String>` object?

#### Code

The transform that is causing the `setCoder` error is this one:

```
package transforms;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONTreeToPaths extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<List<String>>> {

    public static class ExtractPathsFromTree extends SimpleFunction<JsonNode, List<String>> {
        public List<String> apply(JsonNode root) {
            List<String> pathContainer = new ArrayList<>();
            getPaths(root, "", pathContainer);
            return pathContainer;
        }
    }

    public static class GetRootNode extends SimpleFunction<String, JsonNode> {
        public JsonNode apply(String jsonString) {
            try {
                return getRoot(jsonString);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<List<String>> expand(PCollection<String> input) {
        return input
            .apply(MapElements.via(new GetRootNode()))
            .apply(MapElements.via(new ExtractPathsFromTree()));
    }

    private static JsonNode getRoot(String jsonString) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readTree(jsonString);
    }

    private static void getPaths(JsonNode node, String currentPath, List<String> paths) {
        //check if leaf:
        if (node.path("children").isMissingNode()) {
            currentPath += node.get("Id");
            paths.add(currentPath);
            System.out.println(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        // recursively iterate over children
        currentPath += (node.get("Id") + ",");
        for (JsonNode child : node.get("children")) {
            getPaths(child, currentPath, paths);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the error message seems to imply that the list of strings is what needs encoding, it is actually the `JsonNode`. I just had to read a little further down in the error message, as the opening statement is a bit deceiving as to where the issue is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for Traverse Json tree/MapElements/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).output [PCollection@1324829744]. 
...
...
Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder 
for com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.
Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
```

Once I discovered this, I solved the problem by extending Beam's `CustomCoder` class. This abstract class is nice because you only have to write the code to serialize and deserialize the object:

```
public class JsonNodeCoder extends CustomCoder<JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public void encode(JsonNode node, OutputStream outStream) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String nodeString = mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        outStream.write(nodeString.getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode decode(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = new String(bytes);
        return mapper.readTree(json);
    }
}
```

Hopes this helps some other Beam newbie out there.